# Autosys job in windows fails to copy all files but doesnt fail

Tags: autosys

We have a BOX scheduled in Autosys. If the BOX gets triggered at the scheduled time, all the PDFs generated out of one of the steps is not getting copied but the job is also not failing. When we are HOLDING the box and running step by step all outputs are getting copied.

Answer (score 0):

A good troubleshooting step would be to either add in a sleep/delay step of a short time between the generation of the files and the downstream jobs.

A better way might be to use a file trigger or file watcher that will only let the below steps proceed if the files are all there (you can trigger on number of files or whatever stat is appropriate).

If your copy step is a simple copy command without any validation (like copy abc_file_*.pdf) then it wouldn't have any trouble copying whatever files it sees, even if not as many as you intend.